# According to my query it should not return values. but is shows some values

Tags: mysql

**I want to receive data between a date range i have used below mentioned query to to retrieve it. but if i enter a date which record are not entered it shows last 3 day records.**

This is my query

```
SELECT date
     , employee
  FROM daily_sale
 WHERE employee = '$emp' 
    OR  employee = 'both'  
   AND date BETWEEN '$from' and '$to' 
 ORDER 
    BY date DESC
```

**

> what i want is to search how many  dates one employee have worked in
> given dates. employee tabel values are 'L', 'D' and 'Both'. so if i
> search with 'L' i want to receive dates which has 'L' and 'Both'
> values in that tabel

**

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to **sql injection** so pöease use only **prepared stetements with parameters**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to correct your filter criteria like group your `OR` clause in brackets so that rest of the date range filter should be applied correctly

```
SELECT `date`,`employee` 
FROM `daily_sale` 
WHERE (`employee` = :emp OR  `employee` = 'both')
  AND date BETWEEN :from and :to 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Also don't use variables directly in query instead use prepared statements

Comment: this is vulnerable to **sql injection**

Comment: @nbk that is why I have mentioned for prepared statements

Comment: yes, but that is not enough, bad code is everywhere, so at least answers should be proper